# Excel VBA : Looping through same functions using different cell value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

My workbook has 3 sheets.

1. Main
   [image]
2. RawImport
   [image]
3. PullData
   [image]

I am entering my inputs on Main sheet `B2:B5` cells.Depends upon this input I am doing some calculations and saving the results on my sheet RawImport `A8:G8` cells. Now Finally, RawImport `A8:G8` cell values, doing different functions and final results will be saved on PullData `A:L` columns.During this release, user can only use `B2:B5` cells on my `Main` sheet (normally single data set).

Now As part of next version, I would like to have more than one dataset, ie `C2:C5`, `D2:D5`, `E2:E5` etc. But the functions which I run on my other sheets will be exactly same as the first set. For C2:C5, I have to use the next available columns in my other sheet

Main sheet `B2:B5` uses RawImport `A8 :G8`(8 Columns) and PullData `A3:L3`(12 Columns)

Main sheet `C2:C5` uses RawImport `H8:N8`( next 8 columns) and PullData `M3:X3` (next 12 columns)
...
....

Currently, I am writing the same vba scripts multiple times to run the same function. ie, for B2:B5, I uses RawImport `A8 :G8`(8 Columns) and PullData `A3:L3` in my code and for C2:C5 next set of columns in my other sheet. The number of columns used by each set of data will be equal on all the sheet.

The logic which I am following now is, At end of the B2:B5, I will check if C2 is empty and if its empty, I will end my code there, otherwise I will call the code written for C2;C5

Is there anyway I can use a simple way to achieve this rather than writing code multiple times ?

Below is the sample code (Note: This is not the original code, but its similar to original one.)

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()
Dim Main As Worksheet
Dim RawImport As Worksheet
Dim PullData As Worksheet
Dim ticker As String
Dim exchange As String
Dim interval As Integer
Dim numPastTradingDays As Integer
Dim qurl As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'''''''Data Entry to Sheet Main'''''''''''''''

Set Main = Workbooks("1.xlsm").Sheets("Main")
Set RawImport = Workbooks("1.xlsm").Sheets("RawImport")
Set PullData = Workbooks("1.xlsm").Sheets("PullData")

ticker = Main.Range("B2").Value
exchange = Main.Range("B3").Value
interval = Main.Range("B4").Value * 60
numPastTradingDays = Main.Range("B5").Value

'''''''Fill RawImport sheet A to G using Main sheet B2 to B5'''''''''''''''

RawImport.Range("A8").Value = ticker
RawImport.Range("B8").Value = interval
RawImport.Range("C8").Value = 300
RawImport.Range("D8").Value = 400
RawImport.Range("E8").Value = 500
RawImport.Range("F8").Value = exchange
RawImport.Range("G8").Value = interval


'''''''PullData sheet fill using RawImport data from A8 to G8'''''''''''''''

Dim lrA As Integer

lrA = RawImport.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

PullData.Range("A3:A" & lrA - 5).Value = RawImport.Range("G8:G" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("A3:A" & lrA).NumberFormat = "d mmm yyyy h:mm;@"
PullData.Range("A:A").Columns.AutoFit

PullData.Range("B3:B" & lrA - 5).Value = RawImport.Range("E8:E" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("C3:C" & lrA - 5).Value = RawImport.Range("C8:C" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("D3:D" & lrA - 5).Value = RawImport.Range("D8:E" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("E3:E" & lrA - 5).Value = RawImport.Range("B8:B" & lrA).Value
PullData.Range("F3:F" & lrA - 5).Value = RawImport.Range("F8:F" & lrA).Value

PullData.Range("G3:G" & lrA - 5).Formula = "=(C3+D3+E3)/3"
PullData.Range("H3:H" & lrA - 5).Formula = "=G3*F3"
PullData.Range("I3:I" & lrA - 5).Formula = "=sum(H$2:H3)"
PullData.Range("J3:J" & lrA - 5).Formula = "=sum(F$2:F3)"
PullData.Range("K3:K" & lrA - 5).Formula = "=sum(I3/J3)"
PullData.Range("L3:L" & lrA - 5).Formula = "=((E3-K3)/K3)"

PullData.Range("G3:G" & lrA - 5) = PullData.Range("G3:G" & lrA - 5).Value
PullData.Range("H3:H" & lrA - 5) = PullData.Range("H3:H" & lrA - 5).Value
PullData.Range("I3:I" & lrA - 5) = PullData.Range("I3:I" & lrA - 5).Value
PullData.Range("J3:J" & lrA - 5) = PullData.Range("J3:J" & lrA - 5).Value
PullData.Range("K3:K" & lrA - 5) = PullData.Range("K3:K" & lrA - 5).Value
PullData.Range("L3:L" & lrA - 5) = PullData.Range("L3:L" & lrA - 5).Value

PullData.Range("G3:G" & lrA - 5).NumberFormat = "0.00"
PullData.Range("K3:K" & lrA - 5).NumberFormat = "0.00"
PullData.Range("L3:L" & lrA - 5).NumberFormat = "0.00%"

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Am struggling to visualise your set up exactly, but my first thought is that you could add a loop and use Offset to change the relevant range each time.

Comment: I have added the screenshot for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100 % sure, but this should point you in the right direction. What we're doing is a loop, which will continue indefinitely until the cell in row 2 of the next column is empty. I didn't put your entire code within the loop because I'm not going to warrant that it's correct, and I'm not going to troubleshoot every possible line exception you might get. But this is the general concept you'll likely need to implement:

```
Dim collOffset as Long
collOffset = 0

Do While Main.Range("B2").Offset(,collOffset) <> ""
    ticker = Main.Range("B2").Offset(,collOffset).Value
    exchange = Main.Range("B3").Offset(,collOffset).Value
    interval = Main.Range("B4").Offset(,collOffset).Value * 60
    numPastTradingDays = Main.Range("B5").Offset(,collOffset).Value

    '''''''Fill RawImport sheet A to G using Main sheet B2 to B5'''''''''''''''

    RawImport.Range("A8").Offset(,collOffset).Value = ticker
    RawImport.Range("B8").Offset(,collOffset).Value = interval
    RawImport.Range("C8").Offset(,collOffset).Value = 300
    RawImport.Range("D8").Offset(,collOffset).Value = 400
    RawImport.Range("E8").Offset(,collOffset).Value = 500
    RawImport.Range("F8").Offset(,collOffset).Value = exchange
    RawImport.Range("G8").Offset(,collOffset).Value = interval

    ' Etc.
    '
    '
    '  You'll need to add the rest of your code, 
    '  I'm not going to try and reverse-engineer what you did 
    '  or how to fix every line :)


    ' Increment your offset index
    collOffset = collOffset + 1
Loop
```